# e(...).foundation is not a function Foundation 6.4 with Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm new to Foundation 6.4. I have a error when i use $(document).foundation();

Here is following Code:

1.webpack.config.js

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index',
    'script-loader!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script-loader!foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js'],
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './public/bundle.js'
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$|\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['react','es2015'],
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }
};
```

2. index.index

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore,compose} from 'redux';
import reducer from './app/reducers/reducerCombine';
import MainContainer from "./app/container/MainContainer";

require('style-loader!css-loader!foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.min.css');
$(document).ready(()=>$(document).foundation());

const store= createStore(reducer,compose(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MainContainer/>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When i run this app, i got a error in console: Uncaught TypeError: e(...).foundation is not a function.

Anyone can help me^^. Thank in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try importing jQuery and adding it to the window:

```
import { Foundation } from 'foundation-sites';
import jquery from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = jquery;
window.$ = jquery;

Foundation.addToJquery($);

jQuery(document).ready($ => ($(document).foundation()));
```

Comment: Hi Thank for your answer ^^. The way is good, but for the issue i resolved. But i'll vote for your answer!